# Get os.path.join to work with generator?

Tags: python

Trying to get this line of code to work, I keep running into issues no matter how I change the formatting around:

```
if not os.path.exists(os.path.join(IncludeSettings.FILE_URL, [str(x) for x in [year, month, day]])):
```

(year, month, day) can be either ints or strings.

Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/tinyup/dev/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyramid_debugtoolbar-1.0.3-py2.7.egg/pyramid_debugtoolbar/toolbar.py", line 117, in toolbar_tween
    response = _handler(request)
  File "/home/tinyup/dev/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyramid_debugtoolbar-1.0.3-py2.7.egg/pyramid_debugtoolbar/panels/performance.py", line 55, in resource_timer_handler
    result = handler(request)
  File "/home/tinyup/dev/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyramid-1.4a3-py2.7.egg/pyramid/tweens.py", line 20, in excview_tween
    response = handler(request)
  File "/home/tinyup/dev/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyramid-1.4a3-py2.7.egg/pyramid/router.py", line 161, in handle_request
    response = view_callable(context, request)
  File "/home/tinyup/dev/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyramid-1.4a3-py2.7.egg/pyramid/config/views.py", line 342, in rendered_view
    result = view(context, request)
  File "/home/tinyup/dev/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyramid-1.4a3-py2.7.egg/pyramid/config/views.py", line 456, in _class_requestonly_view
    response = getattr(inst, attr)()
  File "/home/tinyup/dev/tinyuploads/tinyuploads/views/share.py", line 56, in view_process
    return self.handle_file_upload(self.request.params['file'], shareID)
  File "/home/tinyup/dev/tinyuploads/tinyuploads/views/share.py", line 101, in handle_file_upload
    self.save(file, newFileName, isImage, uploadTime)
  File "/home/tinyup/dev/tinyuploads/tinyuploads/views/share.py", line 166, in save
    if not os.path.exists(os.path.join(IncludeSettings.FILE_URL, [str(x) for x in [year, month, day]])):
  File "/home/tinyup/dev/lib/python2.7/posixpath.py", line 66, in join
    if b.startswith('/'):
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'startswith'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing the '*' here:

```
>>> os.path.join('foo', *['a','b'])
'foo/a/b'
```

You have to use the star operator here in order to pass the list items as unpacked variable argument list to the method.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what the heck the * does?

Comment: @MasterGberry see [unpacking argument lists](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists) in the Python documentation.

Answer (score 1):

@user1833746 had the answer first, so if you accept any of these, accept that one :)

In addition to the unpacking, if you aren't going to use the resulting list, you can change the `[`'s to `(` to make it a true generator (as opposed to creating a list and then iterating through that). The `*` operator 'unpacks', meaning that the individual components of the item will be passed to the function. As you can see in the code below, `os.path.join` accepts 'two' arguments: `a` (the path name) and `*p` (an arbitrary number of path components). As you can see, you can supply any number of additional path name arguments with this syntax (i.e there are not fixed `path_component1`, `path_component2` variables). In your case, once you get your generator of values, you are 'unpacking' them into individual values (not a single `list` or `generator` object), which `os.path.join` function then handles:

```
In [1]: import os

In [2]: os.path.join('/home/myname', *(str(x) for x in ('one', 'two', 'three')))
Out[2]: '/home/myname/one/two/three'

In [3]: os.path.join??
Type:           function
Base Class:     <type 'function'>
String Form:    <function join at 0x7f4944c31a28>
Namespace:      Interactive
File:           /usr/lib/python2.6/posixpath.py
Definition:     os.path.join(a, *p)
Source:
def join(a, *p):
    """Join two or more pathname components, inserting '/' as needed.
    If any component is an absolute path, all previous path components
    will be discarded."""
    path = a
    for b in p:
        if b.startswith('/'):
            path = b
        elif path == '' or path.endswith('/'):
            path +=  b
        else:
            path += '/' + b
    return path
```

Answer (score 0):

add * before `[str(x) for x in [year, month, day]]`

`*[str(x) for x in [year, month, day]]`

Answer (score 0):

```
if not os.path.exists(os.path.join(IncludeSettings.FILE_URL, str(year), str(month), str(day))):
```

for readability:

```
fname = os.path.join(IncludeSettings.FILE_URL, str(year), str(month), str(day))
if not os.path.exists(fname):
```